# Validating a Text File content using regex

Tags: java, regex

The Input text file has content as following :

TIMINCY........ many arbitrary characters incl. white spaces and tabs

DETAIL........ many arbitrary characters incl. white spaces and tabs

DETAIL........ many arbitrary characters incl. white spaces and tabs

DETAIL........ many arbitrary characters incl. white spaces and tabs

.

.

. (any number of lines containing DETAILS)

TIMINCY........ many arbitrary characters incl. white spaces and tabs

DETAIL........ many arbitrary characters incl. white spaces and tabs

DETAIL........ many arbitrary characters incl. white spaces and tabs

DETAIL........ many arbitrary characters incl. white spaces and tabs

.

.

.(so on)

Q: I need to validate the file using regex so that if the file's content is NOT
in accordance with respect to the pattern given above then I can throw CustomException.

Please let know if you could help. Any help is appreciated cordially.

```
String patternString = "TMINCY"+"[.]\\{*\\}"+";"+"["+"DETAILS"+"[.]\\{*\\}"+";"+"]"+"\\{*\\}"+"]"+"\\{*\\};";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString );
        String messageString = null;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(curracFile.toPath(), charset)) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                builder.append(NEWLINE_CHAR_SEQUENCE);
            }

            messageString = builder.toString();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.error(FILE_CREATION_ERROR, ex.getCause());
            throw new BusinessConversionException(FILE_CREATION_ERROR, ex);
        }   
        System.out.println("messageString is::"+messageString);
        return pattern.matcher(messageString).matches();
```

But it is Returning FALSE for correct file. Please help me with the regex.

Comment: *CORRECTION::The pattern that I am using is: String patternString = "["+"TMINCY"+"[.]\\{*\\}"+";"+"["+"DETAILS"+"[.]\\{*\\}"+";"+"]"+"\\{*\\}"+"]"+"\\{*\\};"; And also, missed to mention the following: private static final String NEWLINE_CHAR_SEQUENCE = ";";

Comment: edit your post instead of writing a comment please. Do you really need to use a REGEX ? Why don't you just read line by line in a loop ?

Comment: Obligatory: https://xkcd.com/1171/

Answer (score 0):

What about something like `"^(TIMINCY|DETAIL)[\.]+[a-zA-z\s.]+"`

`"^"` - matches the start of the line

`"(TIMINCY|DETAIL)"` - matches TIMINCY or DETAIL

`"[\.]"` - matches the dot character to occur one or more times

`"[a-zA-z\s.]+"` - Here you put the allowed characters to occur one or more time

Reference: [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could try line by line when you're iterating over the lines

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:TIMINCY|DETAILS)[.]{8}.*");
//Explanation:
// ^ : Matches the begining of the string.
// (?:): non capturing group.
// [.]{8}: Matches a dot (".") eight times in a row.
// .*: Matches everything until the end of the string
// | : Regex OR operator

String line = reader.readLine()
Matcher m;
while (line  != null) {
    m = p.matcher(line);
    if(!m.matches(line))
        throw new CustomException("Not valid");
    builder.append(line);
    builder.append(NEWLINE_CHAR_SEQUENCE);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Also: `Matcher.matches()` returns true if the ENTIRE STRING matches your regular expression, i would recommend using Matcher.find() to find patterns you don't want.

[Matcher (Java 7)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)